# CentOs server intermittent long response time. [atop screenshot included]

Tags: linux, centos, slow-connection

I am in charge of a website that has about 150 unique users a day. The website hosts forms and gauge data, providing calculations and alerts. It runs well, but for some reason there are intermittent long response times; even for simple requests. For instance I will load one webpage in less than 2 seconds and then another time it will take 20+ seconds to respond. I've even had it take up to 60 seconds before. 3/4 of the time the pages will load fast, but 1/4 of the time it takes much longer to load the same exact same content.  I used htop during the long response times to see if there was a program hogging all the CPU or memory, but I could not get consistent results. Sometimes the server load was high when I got a slow response and sometimes there was nothing running at all when I got a slow response time.

I am new to system administration so I'm struggling to find a good way to pinpoint the error. I've checked all of my logs and found nothing.

Here's a screenshot from atop when a request was taking a while to load:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od8B6.jpg

and here's a screenshot from htop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFisY.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the resources that mysqld seems to be grabbing, it might prove useful to make sure that your settings for mysql are tuned appropriately.

https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/tuning-your-mysql-database

Another helpful tool is [iostat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) which can give you a more clear picture of what your disks are doing at the time of the stall.

And there's always tcpdump, but I might wait until you've exhausted the internal strategies before digging that deep..

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out it was due to a mix of inefficient code and my cruddy internet connection at my house.